# Highcharts with customized markers

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create my customized markers 'plus' and 'minus' for my plots in Highcharts.

This is how I created it, say 'minus':

```
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.plus = function (x, y, w, h) {
            return ['M',x , y + h/2,'L',x + h, y + h/2, '
        };
```

It is very straight forward and it works under JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/szsf6ma6/

however, this doesn't work as expected on my machine. (HighCharts 4.5.2).

I am quite confused about this, does HighCharts 4.5.2 change the way they plot markers?

Comment: I'm sure you are making a mistake on your machine.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work, and what the problem is?

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for the comments and I tried to check the code line by line and it turns out that I didn't specify "lineWidth" parameter in marker.